# Using ES6 Arrow Functions in Node 0.11 w/ Foo.prototype

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-harmony, arrow-functions

I'm getting what I see as unexpected behavior in using arrow functions inside a prototype extension.

```
function ES6Example(){}
ES6Example.prototype.foo = function(bar){
  return ((baz) => {
    console.log(this)
    this.bar = baz
  })(bar)
}

var es6Example = new ES6Example
es6Example.foo('qux')

console.info(es6Example.bar)
```

The above code results in the global context being printed out, as well as `es6Example.bar` being undefined. This is the old behavior. Based on the docs I've seen in MDN I expected this to be bound to the instance. I am running the above code using Node v0.11.15 using the harmony flag. Note that the following does work:

```
function ES6Example(){
    this.foo = baz => {
      this.bar = baz
    }
}
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28029523/218196

Answer (score 2, accepted):

V8 implementation is still incomplete, there's still no lexical `this`.

That's why, in Chrome node.js and io.js, you must set a special "harmony" parameter to use it : it's not ready for general consumption.

Comment: `this` gets passed through if I assign to foo inside the constructor. It only doesn't work in prototype.

Comment: What you see is the same `this` than with normally bound contexts. The lexical `this` isn't yet implemented. The arrow function is also said buggy, you should wait for the V8 team to finish it in my opinion.

Comment: Adrian Perez at Igalia is implementing arrow functions in v8. He is very close to landing the final patch for handling `this`, but there are just a few breakages in TurboFan to iron out: https://codereview.chromium.org/883823002/