# Arrow function context in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

Using the following example from the MDN documentation for Arrow functions, at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

```
function Person(){
  this.age = 0;

  setInterval(() => {
    this.age++; // |this| properly refers to the person object
  }, 1000);
}

var p = new Person();
```

When I copy/paste that code into node.js 0.12 `node --harmony`, the `this.age++;` line doesn't seem to be referring to `Person` context, but rather the `setInterval` context. Adding `console.log(this)` to the callback seems to confirm that.

When I've used other es6->es5 transpilers, it has always worked as expected. Is this a bug in node.js? Am I missing something?

edit: perhaps this is the reason? [ES6 arrow function lexical this in V8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28029523/es6-arrow-function-lexical-this-in-v8)

Difference is, they're discussing Chrome while this question is about Node.js. According to http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#arrow_functions they have different levels of ES6 support even though they both use V8.

Comment: Sure looks like you've found the reason. That question was from just under a month ago.

Comment: as @JLRishe noted, if you've found a solution you should post an answer to this question and accept it.

Comment: Just posted the answer, but I was hoping someone else could confirm before I did that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the reason is that V8 has not updated to support lexical `this` yet.